# When you work for a particular city, do you say "I work at the name of that particular city?"

Tags: prepositions

What is the correct preposition for describing the city you work at? For instance, would I say

> I work at the City of New York

Comment: This whole post is confusing. Do you want the answer to the question in your title or the question that asks about the title? For the latter: the site doesn't do proofreading, and for the former, the question is self-contradicting. You just phrased it "I work *for Chicago, so should I say I work *at* Chicago?".

Answer (score 4):

Yes, your question is gramatically correct.

If I worked for the city of New York I'd say it like this:

"I work for the city of New York"

or

"I work for the city of Seattle"

By saying it like that it makes it clear that you're an employee of the city government.

If you simply worked *in* the city (as a baker for example), then you'd say:

"I work in New York as a baker"